# How to implement Token auth for Liferay DXP JSON remote services?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I need to enable Token-based authentication for Liferay JSON remote services. In short, a guest user should be able to pass in a token while accessing a service, and this token is validated inside an auth pipeline and allows the user to use the service or deny it.
How to implement this in Liferay DXP 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

If it a custom token handling you need to implement, you could use [AutoLogin](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018161711-Auto-Login)
to have an access to the HTTP request and handle custom tokens part of header or param fields.
Otherwise, it is more common to use oauth2 tokens as liferay has a good build in handling for this (but I am not sure about the 7.0 version).

Comment: Hi, I configured the token SSO in Liferay to pass in the token on the request header and implemented the autologin as given in the documentation. It didn't reach the autologin class when I called the service. It gave me the following exception 
 "Access denied to remote.service.test.service.FooService#sum"

Comment: In this case, you need to add an "Service Access Policy" entry in your portal configuration (ControlPanel). I would assume that it is "SYSTEM_USER_PASSWORD" (not sure). Add here your Service class and method name according to your exception.